# How do i format a numeric number to Exponential form in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to format a numeric number to display in exponential form. e.g 140500.45 as 1.4050045E5 using NumberFormat class in Dart. How do i go about this in flutter.
The following is what i have tried so far;

```
 `NumberFormat  numbFormat = NumberFormat("E", "en_US");
  returnFormat = numbFormat.format(numericNumber);
  print(returnFormat);`
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use toStringAsExponential dart functions to format the Numeric value. you may find more from given link: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/num/toStringAsExponential.html

Comment: Thanks, but the value i am passing to toStringAsExponential method is a double, the method only accept integer. i cant use integer in my case because my value is a double and i would loose precision if i cast it to integer. Any Workaround?

Comment: `double` has that method as well.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer Yes double has method toStringAsExponential but like i said earlier the method only accept integer, and i need to supply double as  argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i eventually solved the problem;

```
  double resultme = 140500.45;
  double myreturnFormat = resultMe;
  returnFormat = myreturnFormat.toStringAsExponential();
  print(returnFormat);
```

The output is now correctly  1.4050045e+5 
What i was initial doing wrong is supplying double argument to toStringAsExponential() method. The method requires no argument to return the results without rounding up the result. If you desire to return result such as 1.405e+5, do it like so;

```
myreturnFormat.toStringAsExponential(3);
```

The output will be 1.405e+5
Hope this help someone.